# Android app crashes even after proguard rules are specified

Tags: java, android, twilio, proguard

I have a video calling Android app built with Twilio that I'm trying to publish. I use the bundle tool to install the generated signed bundle in my connected android device. However, I'm get a runtime exception while answering an incoming video call.

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewGlobalRef called with pending exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "tvi.webrtc.WebRtcClassLoader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.demo.app-dOUL_EUaQs_CwBerkm7P8w==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.demo.app-dOUL_EUaQs_CwBerkm7P8w==/split_config.ar.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.demo.app-dOUL_EUaQs_CwBerkm7P8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.demo.app-dOUL_EUaQs_CwBerkm7P8w==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.demo.app-dOUL_EUaQs_CwBerkm7P8w==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.demo.app-dOUL_EUaQs_CwBerkm7P8w==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.demo.app-dOUL_EUaQs_CwBerkm7P8w==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.demo.app-dOUL_EUaQs_CwBerkm7P8w==/split_config.ar.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.demo.app-dOUL_EUaQs_CwBerkm7P8w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.demo.app-dOUL_EUaQs
2020-10-06 16:57:52.411 3350-3350/com.demo.app A/m.kaauh.patien: java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
2020-10-06 16:57:52.411 3350-3350/com.demo.app A/m.kaauh.patien: java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
2020-10-06 16:57:52.411 3350-3350/com.demo.app A/m.kaauh.patien: java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
```

(The stack trace is very lengthy but I hope the issue is clear after reading the first line itself)

I use the default `android.enableR8=true` and the rules are specified in `proguard-rules.pro`

```
# required by twilio plugin
-keep class tvi.webrtc.** { *; }
-dontwarn tvi.webrtc.**
-keep class com.twilio.video.** { *; }
-keep class com.twilio.common.** { *; }
-keepattributes InnerClasses
```

and my app `build.gradle` specifies the release configs

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
signingConfig signingConfigs.release
```

Not sure what I'm missing. Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You use `tvI.webrtc` but should `tvO.webrtc`

Just copy and paste code below

Voice Android 3.2.0+

```
# Twilio Programmable Voice
-keep class com.twilio.** { *; }
-keep class tvo.webrtc.** { *; }
-dontwarn tvo.webrtc.**
-keep class com.twilio.voice.** { *; }
-keepattributes InnerClasses
```